# Using a pipe to read a file, run script and write to the same file

Tags: bash

I need to write a script with one line that gets a file and print on the same file on the end of each line the numbers of words on the sentence only if the word "word" Appears on it. I can use another script that can do what ever I want.
My problem is that after I run the script the file is empty, the file that I sent to the script.

This is the one line script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | ./words_num word | cat $1
```

#### words_num

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    temp=`echo $line | grep $1 | wc -l`
    if (($temp==1)); then
        word_cnt=`echo $line | wc -w`
        echo "$line $word_cnt" 
    else 
        echo "$line"
    fi  
done
```

For example, before the file is:

```
bla bla blaa word
words blaa
bla bla
```

after file:

```
bla bla blaa word 4
words blaa 2
bla bla
```

Can you help?

Comment: `1. Save into another file 2. Delete old one 3. Rename the new file name as the old one` Or you could read the whole file into a variable and iterate over it. Then save into the same file.

Comment: You say 'sentences', but you seem to annotate 'lines' and not 'sentences' (as in, sequences of words terminated by a full stop, question mark or exclamation mark — with complications for quotes and parentheses, etc).  Do you really mean 'number of words on each line where the word "word" appears'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat $1 | ./words_num word | tee $1
```

Comment: thank you, I have another question if I can, when I run the script I got the file as output to the screen, how can I cancel it?

Comment: This works mostly by luck on small files — up to a few kilobytes, if you're lucky.  How big depends on the size of the pipe buffer on the O/S you're working on, which can be from about 4 KiB (POSIX minimum) to 64 KiB or so, but is often 5 KiB (historical precedent). It also depends on the shell launching `cat` before it launches `tee`, and scheduling being kind to you.  If you work on files that are megabytes in size, this will fail.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is there any solution for big files?!

Comment: @ovgolovin: `./words_num word < $1 | tee tmp.$$; mv tmp.$$ $1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, I see. Do we need `tee` at all then (instead for example `<$1 >tmp.$$`)? Also, why won't you write is as a separate answer? I think this is a more general solution than that with `tee` suitable only for small files.

Comment: It isn't clear that we need the `tee`.  In the answer, it copies the new content of the file to standard output (and to the file).  I kept the same idea in my comment.  Looking at the question with its 'cat $1 | ./words_num word | cat $1` structure, then the code is really weird. What's shown should not corrupt the file.  (The word counting script cries out for a rewrite using `awk`  or Perl or Python or...).

Comment: @ovgolovin: I've done what you suggested - supplied a more thorough answer.  I think that covers most of what was discussed.

Answer (score 5):

The one-liner:

```
cat $1 | ./words_num word | cat $1
```

is peculiar.  It is approximately equivalent to:

```
cat $1 | ./words_num word >/dev/null; cat $1
```

which is unlikely to be the intended result.  It is also a candidate for a UUOC (Useless Use of `cat`) award.

If the intention is to overwrite the original file with the amended version, then you should probably write:

```
./words_num word < $1 > tmp.$$; mv tmp.$$ $1
```

If you want to see the results on the screen as well, then:

```
./words_num word < $1 | tee tmp.$$; mv tmp.$$ $1
```

Both these will leave a temporary file around if interrupted.  You can avoid that with:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "rm -f tmp.$$; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
./words_num word < $1 | tee tmp.$$
mv tmp.$$ $1
trap 0
```

The trap sets signal handlers (EXIT, HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE, TERM) and removes the temporary file (if it exists) and exits with a failure status.  The `trap 0` at the end cancels the exit trap so the command exits successfully.

As for the `words_num` script, that seems to call for `awk` rather than shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# == 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 word [file ...]" >&2; exit 1; }
word=$1
shift
awk "/$word/"' { print $0, NF; next } { print }' "$@"
```

You can reduce that if you're into code golfing your `awk` scripts, but I prefer clarify to sub-par code.  It looks for lines containing the word, prints the line along with the number of fields in the line, and moves to the next line.  If the line doesn't match, it is simply printed.  The assignment and shift mean that `"$@"` contains all the other arguments to `words_num`, and `awk` will automatically cycle through the named files, or read standard input if no files are named.

The script should check that the given word does not contain any slashes as that will mess up the regex (it would be OK to replace each one that appears with `[/]`, a character class containing only a slash).  That level of bullet-proofing is left for the interested user.